# Alien Invasion - Pygame - Aliens going off screen

Tags: python, pygame, project

I'm making the Alien Invasion game project from the Python Crash Course book and got stuck with the part where the alien fleet should go right until they reach the right edge of the screen, change direction and go left, and so forth.

The problem is my aliens indeed change direction but only when the first alien in the block (the first one all the way on the left) hits the right edge of the screen. All the aliens right of him go past the right edge.

It seems that it doesn't recognize the rect from the aliens on the right which should hit the right edge first but only the rect from the first alien all the way on the left...

[1. Starting Position Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CIsyN.png)

[2. The Problem Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S5UO6.png)

I'm following closely the instructions from the book, and I checked 3 times now where the problem could be. Could you help me find the problem, please?

**alien_invasion.py**

```
import sys
import pygame
from settings import Settings
from ship import Ship
from bullet import Bullet
from alien import Alien

class AlienInvasion:
    """Overall class to manage game assets and behavior."""

    def __init__(self):
        """Initialize the game, and create game resources."""
        pygame.init()
        self.settings = Settings()
        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((0, 0), pygame.FULLSCREEN)
        self.settings.screen_width = self.screen.get_rect().width
        self.settings.screen_height = self.screen.get_rect().height
        pygame.display.set_caption("Alien Invasion")
        self.ship = Ship(self)
        self.bullets = pygame.sprite.Group()
        self.aliens = pygame.sprite.Group()

        self._create_fleet()

        # Set the background color.
        self.bg_color = (230, 230, 230)

    def run_game(self):
        """Start the main loop for the game."""
        while True:
            self._check_events()
            self.ship.update()
            self._update_bullets()
            self._update_aliens()
            self._update_screen()

    def _check_events(self):
        """Respond to keypresses and mouse events."""
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                sys.exit()
            elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                self._check_keydown_events(event)   
            elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                self._check_keyup_events(event)

    def _check_keydown_events(self, event):
        """Respond to keypresses."""
        if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
            # Move the ship to the right.
            self.ship.moving_right = True
        elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
            # Move the ship to the left.
            self.ship.moving_left = True
        elif event.key == pygame.K_q:
            # Exit the game after pressing Q:
            sys.exit()
        elif event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
            self._fire_bullet()

    def _check_keyup_events(self, event):
        """Respond to keypresses."""
        if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
            # Stop moving the ship to the right.
            self.ship.moving_right = False
        elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
            # Stop moving the ship to the left.
            self.ship.moving_left = False

    def _fire_bullet(self):
        """Create a new bullet and add it to the bullets group."""
        if len(self.bullets) < self.settings.bullets_allowed:
            new_bullet = Bullet(self)
            self.bullets.add(new_bullet)

    def _update_bullets(self):
        """Update position of bullets and get rid of old bullets."""
        # Update bullets positions.
        self.bullets.update()

        # Get rid of bullets that have dissapeared.
        for bullet in self.bullets.copy():
            if bullet.rect.bottom <= 0:
                self.bullets.remove(bullet)

    def _update_aliens(self):
        """Check if the fleet is at an edge, then update the positions of all aliens in the fleet."""
        self._check_fleet_edges()
        """Update the positios of all aliens in the fleet."""
        self.aliens.update()

    def _create_fleet(self):
        """Create a fleet of aliens."""
        # Create an alien and find the number of aliens in a row.
        # Spacing between each alien is equal to one alien width.
        alien = Alien(self)
        alien_width, alien_height = alien.rect.size
        available_space_x = self.settings.screen_width - (2 * alien_width)
        number_aliens_x = available_space_x // (2 * alien_width)

        # Determine the number of rows of aliens that fit on the screen.
        ship_height = self.ship.rect.height
        available_space_y = (self.settings.screen_height - (3 * alien_height) - ship_height)
        number_rows = available_space_y // (4 * alien_height)

        # Create the full fleet of aliens.
        for row_number in range(number_rows):
            for alien_number in range(number_aliens_x):
                self._create_alien(alien_number, row_number)
            
    def _create_alien(self, alien_number, row_number):
        # Create an alien and place it in the row.
        alien = Alien(self)
        alien_width, alien_height = alien.rect.size
        alien.x = alien_width + 4 * alien_width * alien_number
        alien.rect.x = alien.x
        alien.rect.y = alien.rect.height + 3 * alien.rect.height * row_number
        self.aliens.add(alien)

    def _check_fleet_edges(self):
        """Respond appropriately if any aliens have reached an edge."""
        for alien in self.aliens.sprites():
            if alien.check_edges():
                self._change_fleet_direction()
            break

    def _change_fleet_direction(self):
        """Drop the entire fleet and change the fleet's direction."""
        for alien in self.aliens.sprites():
            alien.rect.y += self.settings.fleet_drop_speed
        self.settings.fleet_direction *= -1

    def _update_screen(self):
        """Update images on the screen, and flip to the new screen."""
        self.screen.fill(self.settings.bg_color)
        self.ship.blitme()
        for bullet in self.bullets.sprites():
            bullet.draw_bullet()
        self.aliens.draw(self.screen)

        pygame.display.flip()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Make a game instance, and run the game.
    ai = AlienInvasion()
    ai.run_game()
```

**settings.py**

```
class Settings:
    """A class to store all settings for Alien Invasion."""

    def __init__(self):
        """Initialize the game's settings."""
        # Screen settings
        self.screen_width = 1200
        self.screen_height = 800
        self.bg_color = (230, 230, 230)
        self.ship_speed = 1.5

        # Bullet settings
        self.bullet_speed = 1.0
        self.bullet_width = 3
        self.bullet_height = 15
        self.bullet_color = (60, 60, 60)
        self.bullets_allowed = 3

        # Alien settings
        self.alien_speed = 1.0
        self.fleet_drop_speed = 10
        # fleet_direction of 1 represents right; -1 represents left.
        self.fleet_direction = 1
```

**alien.py**

```
import pygame
from pygame.sprite import Sprite

class Alien(Sprite):
    """A class to represent a single alien in the fleet."""

    def __init__(self, ai_game):
        """Initialize the alien and set its starting postion."""
        super().__init__()
        self.screen = ai_game.screen
        self.settings = ai_game.settings

        # Load the alien image and set its rect attribute.
        self.image = pygame.image.load('images/alien.bmp')
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

        # Start each new alien near the top left of the screen.
        self.rect.x = self.rect.width
        self.rect.y = self.rect.height

        # Store the alien's exact horizontal position.
        self.x = float(self.rect.x)

    def check_edges(self):
        """Return True if an alien is at edge of screen."""
        screen_rect = self.screen.get_rect()
        if self.rect.right >= screen_rect.right or self.rect.left <= 0:
            return True

    def update(self):
        """Move the alien right or left."""
        self.x += self.settings.alien_speed * self.settings.fleet_direction
        self.rect.x = self.x
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a matter of [Indentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html). You need to find the first alien that hits an edge and then break the loop. Actually, you always break the loop after the first enemy in the list:

```py
class AlienInvasion:
    # [...]

    def _check_fleet_edges(self):
        """Respond appropriately if any aliens have reached an edge."""
        for alien in self.aliens.sprites():
            if alien.check_edges():
                self._change_fleet_direction()

                #-->| INDENTATION
                break
            
            # break <-- DELETE
```